# WPF - Listbox bound to collection acts as one item

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a listbox with the ItemsControl binding the ItemsSource to a readonly collection of strings.

The ItemTemplate then declares the DataTemplate as a checkbox where its content is that of the name of the particular item in the collection and IsChecked bound to a property to determine whether or not the item is selected (it's just a listbox of checkboxes)

This works fine with one exception - MouseOver the ListBox and it acts as if the collection of Strings is a single item; the whole box acts as if selected. This wouldn't be as much of a problem were it not for this also affecting the scrollbars where they won't get enabled - presumably because it considers the one item as being visible on the screen even though it in actual facts is x+ with only x-y showing on the screen.

How do I get the listbox to act as if each individual string is its own item. I assume it acts this way because I declared a datatemplate in order to get a listbox of checkboxes??

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` directly for displaying your items, not a `ListBox`. The `ListBox` add the notion of selection, which you don't need.